# Issue with global expo-cli package and unable to find expo

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, deprecated, npx

[this happened when i entered npx expo start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQop6.png)
im confused ive been trying to get my program running but it keeps displaying this message:

|   The global expo-cli package has been deprecated.                        |
│                                                                           │
│   The new Expo CLI is now bundled in your project in the expo package.    │
│   Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.        │
│                                                                           │
│   To use the local CLI instead (recommended in SDK 46 and higher), run:   │
│   › npx expo                                                     |

pls help me i really need to test if my app can run or not

i tried installing a new version of nvm that solved one of the persistent problems and i also tried uninstalling and installing expo that didnt work, i went to the website they linked me to and did everything but that didnt work and was confused by the steps too. i then searched up help and here i am. pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error when you run the command `expo start`.  That is attempting to run the `expo` command that you have installed globally.  But that command is now deprecated.  I recommend that you uninstall it, which you can typically do with `npm uninstall -g expo-cli`.

When you run `npx expo ....` then the NPM system checks to see if the `expo` command is in your current node project, which it will run.  If it is not, then `npx` will go and fetch the `expo` command and locally install it to your current project.  Once installed, running `npx expo ....` again will immediately run.